# mysqli_init()でエラーとなるケース

Tags: php

mysqli_real_connect()を使ってmysqlに接続するときに公式のドキュメントを見ると以下のようになっています。

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_init();
if (!$link) {
    die('mysqli_init failed');
}

if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
}

if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
}

if (!mysqli_real_connect($link, 'localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db')) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

mysqli_init()でエラーになってdie('mysqli_init failed')におちるケースはどういったパターンなんでしょうか。

Comment: 前の`mysql_init`ではメモリが不足すると`NULL`が来てました。もしくは`mysqli_init`が2回呼び出されるとか、`mysqli`が正しくセットアップされていないとか？、深く考えたことないので自信ないです。何らかの理由で割り当てに失敗するとエラー出しそうですね。

Comment: メモリ不足だとNULLになっていたのですね。mysqli_init()ではどうなんでしょう。